# If I take a loss when I sell my car, can I claim a capital loss deduction on my income tax return?

Tags: taxes, canada, tax-deduction, car, capital-loss

If I sell my car off at a loss, can I write that loss off against my income to save on tax? Does it matter if the car was used just for personal leisure use, or if I used the car to generate business income? (e.g. travel to work, to attend education seminars, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you'd need to pay tax if you realized a capital *gain* on the sale of your car, you generally can't deduct any *loss* arising from the sale of ["personal use property"](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/ncm-tx/rtrn/cmpltng/rprtng-ncm/lns101-170/127/glssry-eng.html#Personaluseproperty). Cars are personal use property.

Refer to [Canada Revenue Agency – Personal-use property losses](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/ncm-tx/rtrn/cmpltng/rprtng-ncm/lns101-170/127/cmpltng/prsnls/prsnl-eng.html).  Quote:

> [...] if you have a capital loss, you usually **cannot** deduct that
>   loss when you calculate your income for the year. In addition, you
>   cannot use the loss to decrease capital gains on other personal-use
>   property. This is because if a property depreciates through personal
>   use, the resulting loss on its disposition is a personal expense.

There are some exceptions. Read up at the source links.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But if I use the car to generate income (i.e get to work, lease it out for a day), is it still considered personal use or does it qualify as business expense?

Comment: The loss on the sale of the car doesn't qualify as a business expense. If you were claiming a portion of your car expenses as a business expense, you would have had an opportunity, each year, to claim a portion of the Capital Cost Allowance (CCA) for the vehicle. CCA is a form of depreciation. Did you do that?

Comment: Have a look at [Form T777 (PDF)](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/E/pbg/tf/t777/t777-13e.pdf) ... the middle section on the first page is for calculating your allowable automobile expenses. Line 9 is the capital cost allowance, and the next page in the document describes how to calculate it. You'll also want to refer to [Guide T4044 (PDF)](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/E/pub/tg/t4044/t4044-lp-12e.pdf). Note that if you are an **employee**, you can only claim such expenses if your employer provides you with a T2200 slip permitting such. Only some kinds of employees can deduct car expenses -- most cannot.